Problemas con mi Sitio Web
Estoy teniendo problemas con mi sitio web, cabe aclarar que no soy desarrollador web, así que mucho del tema no se, si alguien podría ayudarme guiándome a solucionar los errores que estoy teniendo lo agradecería.

Error que aparece al iniciar el sitio web:Fatal error: Uncaught Dotenv\Exception\InvalidPathException: Unable to read any of the environment file(s) at [/home/u480919613/domains/vamplix.dev/public_html/bloomweb/private/.env]. in /home/u480919613/domains/vamplix.dev/public_html/bloomweb/vendor/vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Store/FileStore.php:68 Stack trace: #0 /home/u480919613/domains/vamplix.dev/public_html/bloomweb/vendor/vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Dotenv.php(222): Dotenv\Store\FileStore->read() #1 /home/u480919613/domains/vamplix.dev/public_html/bloomweb/index.php(10): Dotenv\Dotenv->load() #2 {main} thrown in /home/u480919613/domains/vamplix.dev/public_html/bloomweb/vendor/vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Store/FileStore.php on line 68

Todo mi script esta hecho en PHP, la idea o lo que quería lograr/esperaba ver era un sitio web el cual luego pueda pasar al dominio oficial, es decir esta es un prueba como tal, la idea principal es poder conectarla a un servidor VPS una vez me llegue, pero realmente al comienzo era que funcionen los apartados, para que una vez este listo el servidor VPS sea conectarlo a través de la IP y dominio para que proporcione cierta información.
De ante mano cave aclarar que la idea es que haya una extensión hacia otro dominio el cual sea el panel de los administradores (aun no esta listo el código/diseño pero me parecía bueno comentarlo)
Tras esto luego de ver guías, foros, hablar con el soporte de hostinger no hemos podido encontrar el error y me recomendó venir aquí.

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Dotenv\Store;

use Dotenv\Exception\InvalidPathException;
use Dotenv\Store\File\Reader;

final class FileStore implements StoreInterface
{
    /**
     * The file paths.
     *
     * @var string[]
     */
    private $filePaths;

    /**
     * Should file loading short circuit?
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    private $shortCircuit;

    /**
     * The file encoding.
     *
     * @var string|null
     */
    private $fileEncoding;

    /**
     * Create a new file store instance.
     *
     * @param string[]    $filePaths
     * @param bool        $shortCircuit
     * @param string|null $fileEncoding
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(array $filePaths, bool $shortCircuit, string $fileEncoding = null)
    {
        $this->filePaths = $filePaths;
        $this->shortCircuit = $shortCircuit;
        $this->fileEncoding = $fileEncoding;
    }

    /**
     * Read the content of the environment file(s).
     *
     * @throws \Dotenv\Exception\InvalidEncodingException|\Dotenv\Exception\InvalidPathException
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function read()
    {
        if ($this->filePaths === []) {
            throw new InvalidPathException('At least one environment file path must be provided.');
        }

        $contents = Reader::read($this->filePaths, $this->shortCircuit, $this->fileEncoding);

        if (\count($contents) > 0) {
            return \implode("\n", $contents);
        }

        throw new InvalidPathException(
            \sprintf('Unable to read any of the environment file(s) at [%s].', \implode(', ', $this->filePaths))
        );
    }
}


Lo primero que podrías hacer si quieres ayuda es publicar el contenido de tu script FileStore.php ya que el mensaje indica que tienes un error en la linea 68.

Listo, muchas gracias por el consejo, es la primera vez que uso esto

El Error en la linea 68 viene de use Dotenv\Exception\InvalidPathException; verifica si las rutas están bien definidas.

Mira si existe este archivo o si existe si tiene los permisos adecuados: /home/u480919613/domains/vamplix.dev/public_html/bloomweb/private/.env pues diria que se queja de que no lo encuentra o no lo sabe leer con los permisos actuales, o quizás tiene algun tipo de sintaxis inválida para la función Reader::read (que no se que hace realmente).

Segun este issue, debe haber al menos un .env en la raiz del proyecto. Revisa las otras respuestas en el hilo a ver si se acomoda a tu situación. Verifica que tengas composer y un autoloader desde  /vendor/autoload.php.

¿Usas algún framework? ¿Lo instalaste o sólo copiaste todos los archivos?
